# Physics interpretation of magnetic susceptibility in paramagnet

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

I'm modeling a paramagnetic salt with $H=JS_iS_j$, which represents the interaction between two magnetic atoms $i$ and $j$ of the salt.
The modulus of $S$ is $1/2$ and $J$ is positive. 
I have the singlet state with $E=-3J/4$ and the triplet state with $E=J/4$. 
Suppose we apply a weak magnetic field $B$ and the energy of the triplet split into $$E_+=\frac{J}{4}+\gamma B \\E_-=\frac{J}{4}-\gamma B$$ where $\gamma$ is a constant of the interaction of the field with the atoms.
I know how to get the magnetization $M$ and the magnetic susceptibility $\chi_m$:
$$ \chi_m=2N\gamma^2\beta\frac{\cosh(\gamma\beta B)(e^{J\beta}+1)+2}{(e^{J\beta}+2\cosh(\gamma\beta B)+1)^2}$$
where $\beta$ is $1/k_b T$ and T is the absolute temperature.
What physical interpretation can I get from this magnetization, when $T->0$ or $T->\infty$?
What happens if J is negative?

Comment: Have you tried plotting this as a function of $B$, $J$, or $T$?

Comment: Tried, but i dont know why i get some results depending of B or J i use. Which value of J is usually used here?